# Getting value from HTML table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table that shows some data.

Shown in this table:

[image]

Now I have this button where it will show the value. In this example I want to show every name of every row.

Output sample must be:

```
alert('people.name');//of first row
alert('people.name'); //of second row
alert('people.name'); //and so on
```

I have tried this code but it says undefined:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {

    var name;
    var address;
    var contact;
    var people = [];

    $('#sample tbody tr').each(function () {
        var line = {
            'name': $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').html(),
            'address': $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html(),
            'contact': $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').html()
        };
        people.push(line);
        alert(people.name);
    });
});
```

But what it does is return undefined.
What is the problem? Please help me

My table:

```
<table id="sample">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Dave</td>
        <td>Alpha St.</td>
        <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jade</td>
        <td>Delta St.</td>
        <td>56789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Elsa</td>
        <td>Beta St.</td>
        <td>54321</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mack</td>
        <td>Fox St.</td>
        <td>52324</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: `people` is an array - it does not contain a property named `name`. If you want the first `name` in the collection, use `people[0].name`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this code.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
          $('#btn').click(function () {

    var name;
var address;
var contact;
var people = [];

$('#sample tbody tr').each(function (value,key) {
    var line = {
        'name': $(this).find('td').html(),
        'address': $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html(),
        'contact': $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').html()
    };
    people.push(line);
alert('Name =>   '+ people[value]['name'] +'  Address =>   '+ people[value]['address'] +'  Contact =>  ' + people[value]['contact']);

    });
console.log(people);
});
});
```

**Make sure that in your code id is unique.**

You can you directly display name,contact,address from the array like as below:

```
console.log(people[key]['name']);//need to change key value contact,address.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it and it works. but the only problem is, it only works in name. what if i want to get the address or contact..
my target is I will use `people` as data in my ajax

Comment: I found something wrong in my post. It was my mistake.. What I want is every row, the items will be replace then send to my server, read the next row, items will be replace then send to my server

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#btn').click(function () {

    var people = [];
    $('#sample tbody tr').each(function () {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td');
        var line = {
            name:     $tds.eq(0).text(),
            address:  $tds.eq(1).text(),
            contact:  $tds.eq(2).text()
        };
        people.push(line);        
    });

    var names = '';
    $(people).each(function () {
       names += this.name + ', ';
    });

   alert(names);
});
```

Comment: use   var $tds =  $(this).find('td'); updated my answer as well

Comment: I found something wrong in my post. It was my mistake.. What I want is every row, the items will be replace then send to my server, read the next row, items will be replace then send to my server

Comment: What object do you want to send to the server? people array or a single people object? Explain a little more and share your server side code

Answer (score 0):

eq(i) start from 0

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
var name;
var address;
var contact;
var people = []
 $('#sample tbody tr').each(function () {
    var line = {
        'name': $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(),
        'address': $(this).find('td').eq(1).text(),
        'contact': $(this).find('td').eq(2).text()
    };
    people.push(line);
    alert(people.name);
});
});
```

Comment: still undefined

Comment: may be you have multiple table have #same id

Comment: people is an ARRAY. "people.name" will be undefined. you should access something like this: people[0].name. or use a for loop

Comment: I found something wrong in my post. It was my mistake.. What I want is every row, the items will be replace then send to my server, read the next row, items will be replace then send to my server

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you problem , It will be worked nicely.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#btn').on('click',function () {

    var name;
    var address;
    var contact;
    var people = [];

    $('#sample tbody tr').each(function (key,val) {

        var line = {
            'name': $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html(),
            'address': $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(),
            'contact': $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html()
        };

        people.push(line);

        console.log("NAME: "+people[key]['name']);

        console.log("ADDRESS: "+people[key]['address']);

        console.log("CONTACT: "+people[key]['contact']);

    });

  });
});
```